# Call WCF WsFederationHttpBinding service from .Net Core using STS

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I have an `app.config` to call this service from .Net framework but now I have to do the same from core app. Here's the WCF client config:

```xml
    <bindings>
    <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_certificate" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="true">
              <claimTypeRequirements>
                <add claimType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706/claims/action" isOptional="true"/>
                <add claimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier" isOptional="false"/>
                <add claimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"/>
              </claimTypeRequirements>
              <issuer address="https://some.url.com/STS/Issue.svc/trust/13/certificatemixed" binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="certificateMixed"/>
              <issuerMetadata address="https://some.url.com/STS/Issue.svc/mex"/>

             <!-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM PART -->
              <tokenRequestParameters>
                <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                  <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                    <Address>URN:MY.TEST.SERVICE</Address>
                  </EndpointReference>
                </wsp:AppliesTo>
              </tokenRequestParameters>
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>

      <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="certificateMixed">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007HttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behaviorSECertificate">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="ab cd .. b4" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"
              x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Pretty basic stuff. So now I do the same in .Net core code:

```cs
        var issuerBinding = new WS2007HttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        issuerBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
        issuerBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        issuerBinding.Name = "certificateMixed";

        var prm = new WsTrustTokenParameters
        {
            IssuerBinding = issuerBinding,
            IssuerAddress = new EndpointAddress(_seOptions.STSEndpoint),
            MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10,
            EstablishSecurityContext = false, 
        };

        prm.ClaimTypes.Add(new ClaimType() { Uri = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706/claims/action", IsOptional = true });
        prm.ClaimTypes.Add(new ClaimType() { Uri = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier", IsOptional = false });
        prm.ClaimTypes.Add(new ClaimType() { Uri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", IsOptional = true });

        var binding = new WsFederationHttpBinding(prm);
        binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;

        ChannelFactory<IMyService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(_seOptions.MyServiceUrl));

        var cert = GetClientCertificate(); //X509Certificate2
        var x = factory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors[typeof(ClientCredentials)];
            ((ClientCredentials)x).ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;            
        IMyService client = factory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(_seOptions.MyServiceUrl));
```

So the main question is- how do I add the `tokenRequestParameters/AppliesTo` section in code? I assume it would be something like this:

```
RequestSecurityToken tk = new RequestSecurityToken() { AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress("URN:MY.TEST.SERVICE") };
```

But I have no idea what to assign this object to.

Comment: Hi, May I know how is the issue going on now?
If you do not have any other concerns, please remember to mark the answer.

Comment: Still no success. I managed to get the token from STS (with successfully specifying the AppliesTo) but after that when calling client methods I ran into some "could not load type" exceptions complaining about some interface in Microsoft.IdenityModel libraries that is nowhere to be found in MS docs.

Comment: The wcf features supported in .netcore are very limited, and the binding .net core you are using does not support it, so it is recommended to refer to the wcf features supported in .netcore to redo the functions you want to achieve.Here is the link of reference: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.0.0.md

Answer (score 0):

RequestSecurityToken class is not applicable to .net core,  you can see its support on this page: [RequestSecurityToken Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.protocols.wstrust.requestsecuritytoken?view=netframework-4.8). So you need to find a replacement for it in .net core. You can refer to  [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) to consider how to migrate from .net framework to .net core. Hope my answer will help you.